# How to convert list to int

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to calculate the average of the height of the student
that is my code

```
 height = input("what is your higth\n").split()

for n in range(0, len(height)):

    height[n] = int(height[n])

print(height)


t = 0

for i in height:

    t += height

print(height)
```

and I have error

```
  t += higths

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Your error and code don't even match. Use basic debugging techniques.

Comment: is the user supposed to enter multiple heights with spaces in between?

Comment: The variable `higths` isn't defined in your code. Likewise, this error does not align the code provided. Could you please ensure you're sharing the correct code?

Comment: yes  the user supposed to enter multiple heights with spaces in between

Comment: Your error and code don't even match. Use basic debugging techniques I have used and i have the same error

Comment: What is the height input format,.. 6' 1", 128cm, 0.598 elephants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` on the for loop to access to the list indexes and convert it to `int`.
Then calculate the sum divided by the len of the list.

```
height = input("what is your higth\n").split()

for i, element in enumerate(height) : 
    height[i] = int(element)

# Average
print(sum(height)/len(height))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
height = [ int(h) for h in input("what's your heights\n").strip("[]").replace(","," ").split()]
print(sum(height) / len(height))
```

Demo:

```
what's your heights
1 2 3 4 5 6
3.5

what's your heights
[1, 2 ,3,4 5 6]
3.5
```